# Is having a form on a php page submit to the same page bad practise?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My site (for a school project) needs a dashboard to display tickets.

I was thinking of having the user use inputs to filter the tickets before submiting the form. Depending on the form inputs that were used/unused, the mysql query's where condition would be altered before displaying the tickets in the table.

My question comes in here: Is it bad practise to display the form again below(beside) the table, or should I just link back so the form displays again?

Right now I have something that looks like this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 //run the queries, display the table

 //show the form again??

 }

 else{

 //show the form

 }
```

Comment: This is normal and common

Comment: Probably the closest thing you'll get to documented 'best practice': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it bad practice as much as it is a preference of usability.  However, I would recommend a redirect on the submit page so that the query can be performed on the submit page but then a redirect to a page displaying results.  This will help keep people from accidentally refreshing the post.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // query results ...
    // redirect to display.php
} else {
    // display form
}
```

display.php

```
// display results
```

Also, don't forget to throw in a little error checking :)

Comment: That's a great idea thank you. Yeah I simplified my code tons to get at the more general concept.

Answer (score 0):

No you can do it, no problem. The only issue is if the user do a refresh, it will resubmit the form again.

Also, what you can do is a redirect if the POST is success to avoid a POST resubmit.

Answer (score 0):

It should have more [usability](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-101-introduction-to-usability/) when displayed aside the results.